# Rearranging Formtastic layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, formtastic, stylesheet

I'm completely new to formtastic and pretty unexperienced when it comes to CSS and stylesheets.

I'm trying to rearrange my layout to look like the bottom of this picture: 
[image: http://img242.imageshack.us/img242/3971/layoutiy.jpg]
As you can see I managed to make the dropdowns align nicely, but not the Fee/Consultant Hours.

This is my .erb file;

```
<div id="defaults">
    <% semantic_form_for <more stuff goes here> %>
    ......
    <div id="customer-details">
        <%= form.input :fee %>
        <%= form.input :consultant_hours %>

        <%= form.input :automatic_prolonging, :as => :radio, :collection => [[("Yes"), "true" ]] + [[("No"), 'false']], :wrapper_html => { :class => "compact" } %>
        <%= form.input :customer_segment, :as => :radio, :collection => [[("Industry"), "Industry" ]] +[[("Bank/Finance"), "Bank/Finance" ]] + [[("Products/Services"), 'Products/Services']]+ [[("Organization"), 'Organization']]+[[("Other"), 'Other']], :wrapper_html => { :class => "compact" } %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

I edited my formtastic_changes.css file as follows:

```
#customer-details li{
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    height: 60px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

#customer-details .compact ol li, #social-post-defaults .compact ol li,
#customer-details .compact ol, #social-post-defaults .compact ol {
    width: 220px !important; 
    height: auto !important;
}

#customer-details .compactSelect, #social-post-defaults .compactSelect {
    width: 160px !important;
}

#customer-details .compactSelect ol, #social-post-defaults .compactSelect ol {
    width: 220px !important;
}

#customer-details .compactSelect .field, 
#social-post-defaults .compactSelect .field {
    width: 146px !important;
}

#customer-details .compactSelect ol li, 
#social-post-defaults .compactSelect ol li {
    width: 160px;
    height: auto !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#customer-details .string input {
    width: 285px;
    margin: 2px 0 5px;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

And this is the problem. No matter how much I change the width attribute, nothing changes.
If I remove the ".string", the width changing works, but the fields still don't align next to each other but over/under each other.

I've watched both Formtastic tutorials on railcasts and looked through the formtastic Rdoc but I still don't seem able to solve this problem.

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction? 
Thankful for any help.

Comment: As a suggestion, state your question a little earlier instead of hiding it in a bunch of text. Also, can you add exactly what the generated HTML looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Emil: Try

```
#customer-details input {
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 2px 0 5px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 285px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It looked like this when I tried it: http://img529.imageshack.us/img529/2467/layout2png.png    Still don't know why it wont align next to each other ...